# is Dict.get in Python use is to compare keys in dict?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am using Python2.7 to write `Set` Data Struction. But I got confused to when using `Dict.get`. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:UTF-8
__author__ = 'shenshijun'


class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, key, weight):
        """Constructor for """
        self.key = key
        self.weight = weight

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.key, other.key)

    def __str__(self):
        return "".join(['Node(key=', str(self.key), ',weight=', str(self.weight), ")"])


__dict = {}
a1 = Node('A', 1)
a2 = Node('A', 2)
__dict[a1] = a1
print a1 == a2
print(__dict.get(a2))
```

the output of this code is the following:

`True`
    `None`

So I guess that Python use `is` operator to compare the keys when searching. Can someone one find the truth?

The Python I used:

```
2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]
```

I have just solve my problem, but any suggestions about how to implements `__hash__` in this situation?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but `dict` is a hash map, so it uses the hash code for storing the items into "buckets", and since you do not implement `__hash__`, it uses the default hashcode, i.e. the memory address. And since the hashed do not match, there's no reason to check for equality.

Comment: dicts use `__hash__`, `==` uses `__eq__`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have an equality on a1 and a2, but they are not the same object, indeed the reference has changed, so then

```
print a1 is a2  # False
print(__dict.get(a1)) # Node(key=A,weight=1)
print(__dict.get(a2)) # None
```

a1 is not the same object as a2, the key to a1 references the node, but not a2.

**EDIT**

As @tobias_k says, you can override the [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) function to do a different way to store hash references instead the memory address, for example :

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, key, weight):
        """Constructor for """
        self.key = key
        self.weight = weight

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.key, other.key)

    def __str__(self):
        return "".join(['Node(key=', str(self.key), ',weight=', str(self.weight), ")"])

    def __hash__(self):
        return ord(self.key)

__dict = {}
a1 = Node('A', 1)
a2 = Node('A', 2)
__dict[a1] = a1
print a1 == a2 # True
print a1 is a2 # False 
print(__dict.get(a1)) # Node(key=A,weight=1)
print(__dict.get(a2)) # Node(key=A,weight=1)
```

Comment: the `ord` function used in your version of `__hash__` is nowhere to find in Python builtins. Where did you get it?

Comment: "you can override the `__hash__` function to do a different way to store hash references" I think this is an understatement. This is not a different, but _the right_ way to use a hashmap. Also, whenever you implement `__eq__` or `__cmp__` you _should_ also implement `__hash__` or all sorts of strange things will happen -- as in OP's question.

Comment: I am sorry, maybe it is because english is not my native language. But I am not very sure if i got this point right, i can't see anything wrong about my sentence, or perhaps were you doing some kind of precission i am missing, if it is so, then thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

When you look up a key in a [dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), it does not right away test for equality. At first, it checks the hash code, to determine the "bucket" where the item *should* be if it were in the dictionary, and only *then* it checks for equality.

And since you did not implement a `__hash__` method, it uses the default hash code, i.e. the memory address IIRC, so it never checks for equality in the first place. Add this to your class, then it will work

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.key)
```

Output:

```
True
Node(key=A,weight=1)
```

You can also add some `print` statements to your `__hash__` and `__cmp__` functions to see when and in what order those are called.

---

*Addendum:* It might be worth noting that, while not mandated by the programming language, you should *always* implement `__hash__` when you implement `__eq__` or `__cmp__`, and in such a way that whenever two objects are equal, they also have the same hash code (the converse is not necessary).

For more information, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27581/1639625) (for Java, but just as valid for Python).